# Как определить тип диска (FileStore) в Windows?

Tags: java, windows, файловая-система

Для объектов типа `FileStore` в Windows стандартными и широко известными методами легко определяется метка и буква тома, объем диска и свободного места, пример из документации:

```
    for (FileStore store: FileSystems.getDefault().getFileStores()) {
      long total = store.getTotalSpace() / 1024;
      long used = (store.getTotalSpace() - store.getUnallocatedSpace()) / 1024;
      long avail = store.getUsableSpace() / 1024;
      System.out.format("%-20s \t%,16d \t%,16d \t%,16d%n", store, total, used, avail);
    }
```

Но среди дисков есть локальные, съёмные, сетевые...
Как отличить одни от других, например, если мне нужно обработать только локальные диски? У класса `FileStore` есть метод `getAttribute(String attrName)`, которому нужно передавать имя атрибута, вот цитата из документации:

> Suppose we want to know if ZFS compression is enabled (assuming the
>   "zfs" view is supported):
>
> ```
> boolean compression = (Boolean)fs.getAttribute("zfs:compression");
> ```

но какие `AttributeView` и какие имена атрибутов можно использовать в Windows, мне нигде найти не удалось.

Как можно отличить локальные диски от сетевых и т. п.? Можно ли без большого шаманства (типа запуска сторонних утилит и анализа их выдачи) получить еще какую-то информацию о дисках (физический диск, на котором располжен раздел, тип раздела...), доступную, например, утилите `msinfo32.exe`?

Comment: Может поможет - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17972420/4444092

Comment: @Tsyklop О, спасибо! Я не хочу без большой нужды подключать `JACOB`, но решение с использованием `javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView`, которое там в соседнем ответе приводится, меня вполне устроило, и в другом соседнем ответе есть подсказка для получения атрибутов `FileStore`, которую я не мог найти: `fileStore.getAttribute("volume:isRemovable")`. Если есть желание, опишите эти два варианта в ответе, я галку поставлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать два варианта: использовать [JACOB](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/), воспользоваться `FileStore` классом или воспользоваться классом `FileSystemView`.

`FileStore` можно сделать так:

```
for (Path root : FileSystems.getDefault().getRootDirectories()) {
  FileStore fileStore = Files.getFileStore(root);
  System.out.format("%s\t%s\n", root, fileStore.getAttribute("volume:isRemovable"));
}
```

`FileSystemView` делается так:

```
File[] roots = File.listRoots();
FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();

for (File root : roots) {
    try {

        BasicFileAttributeView basicFileAttributeView = Files.getFileAttributeView(root.toPath(), BasicFileAttributeView.class);

        BasicFileAttributes attributes = basicFileAttributeView.readAttributes();

        System.out.println("File Key: " + attributes.fileKey());
        System.out.println("Is Regular File: " + attributes.isRegularFile());
        System.out.println("Is Other: " + attributes.isOther());
        System.out.println("Is SymbolicLink: " + attributes.isSymbolicLink());
        System.out.println("Is Directory: " + attributes.isDirectory());

        System.out.println("Drive Name: " + root);
        System.out.println("Description: " + fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(root));
        System.out.println("Is Drive: " + fsv.isDrive(root));
        System.out.println("Is File System: " + fsv.isFileSystem(root));
        System.out.println("Is File System Root: " + fsv.isFileSystemRoot(root));
        System.out.println("Is Floppy Drive: " + fsv.isFloppyDrive(root));
        System.out.println("Is Hidden File: " + fsv.isHiddenFile(root));
        System.out.println("Is Traversable: " + fsv.isTraversable(root));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Еще [гайд](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_io/1000__Java_nio_File_Attributes.htm) как можно получить аттрибуты.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48283896/4444092)

Вариант с JACOB:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DrivesExample
{
    public interface HasNativeValue
    {
        int getNativeValue();
    }

    public enum DriveTypeEnum implements HasNativeValue
    {
        Unknown(0),
        NoRootDirectory(1),
        RemovableDisk(2),
        LocalDisk(3),
        NetworkDrive(4),
        CompactDisc(5),
        RAMDisk(6);

        public final int nativeValue;

        DriveTypeEnum(int nativeValue)
        {
            this.nativeValue = nativeValue;
        }

        public int getNativeValue()
        {
            return nativeValue;
        }
    }

    private static <T extends Enum<T> & HasNativeValue> T fromNative(Class<T> clazz, int value)
    {
        for (T c : clazz.getEnumConstants())
        {
            if (c.getNativeValue() == value)
            {
                return c;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * The drive information.
     */
    public static final class Drive
    {
        /**
         * File system on the logical disk. Example: NTFS. null if not known.
         */
        public final String fileSystem;
        /**
         * Value that corresponds to the type of disk drive this logical disk represents.
         */
        public final DriveTypeEnum driveType;
        /**
         * The Java file, e.g. "C:\". Never null.
         */
        public final File file;

        public Drive(String fileSystem, DriveTypeEnum driveType, File file)
        {
            this.fileSystem = fileSystem;
            this.driveType = driveType;
            this.file = file;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Drive{" + file + ": " + driveType + ", fileSystem=" + fileSystem + "}";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Lists all available Windows drives without actually touching them. This call should not block on cd-roms, floppies, network drives etc.
     *
     * @return a list of drives, never null, may be empty.
     */
    public static List<Drive> getDrives()
    {
        List<Drive> result = new ArrayList<>();
        ActiveXComponent axWMI = new ActiveXComponent("winmgmts://");

        try
        {
            Variant devices = axWMI.invoke("ExecQuery", new Variant("Select DeviceID,DriveType,FileSystem from Win32_LogicalDisk"));
            EnumVariant deviceList = new EnumVariant(devices.toDispatch());
            while (deviceList.hasMoreElements())
            {
                Dispatch item = deviceList.nextElement().toDispatch();
                String drive = Dispatch.call(item, "DeviceID").toString().toUpperCase();
                File file = new File(drive + "/");
                DriveTypeEnum driveType = fromNative(DriveTypeEnum.class, Dispatch.call(item, "DriveType").getInt());
                String fileSystem = Dispatch.call(item, "FileSystem").toString();
                result.add(new Drive(fileSystem, driveType, file));
            }

            return result;
        } finally
        {
            closeQuietly(axWMI);
        }
    }

    private static void closeQuietly(JacobObject jacobObject)
    {
        try
        {
            jacobObject.safeRelease();
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments)
    {
        List<Drive> drives = getDrives();

        for (Drive drive : drives)
        {
            System.out.println(drive.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Пример вывода:

```
Drive{C:\: LocalDisk, fileSystem=NTFS}
Drive{D:\: LocalDisk, fileSystem=NTFS}
Drive{E:\: RemovableDisk, fileSystem=NTFS}
Drive{F:\: RemovableDisk, fileSystem=FAT32}
Drive{G:\: RemovableDisk, fileSystem=null}
Drive{Y:\: NetworkDrive, fileSystem=NTFS}
```

Чтобы использовать `JACOB`, добавьте `JAR` и `DLL` в виде библиотек в вашем проекте. Это решение только для Windows.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17972420/4444092)
[Оригинальный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3542018/4444092)